# Linking to an exact duplicate external resource

Tags: discussion

Usually, link-only answers are frowned upon:

- [What is Stack Overflow's take on link only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168712/what-is-stack-overflows-take-on-link-only-answers)
- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

But what if the external resource is the official FAQ of the language and it is the exact question the OP asked?

I've recently closed a duplicate and encountered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it) that already exists in the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x).

According to some other answers on meta I should quote parts of the external resource and modify them to fit the question, but this is the exact same question being asked, deserving of the exact same answer.

I feel like that while trying to avoid a link-only answer, I've ended up [copying everything from the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70813377/1658617) which is probably less than ideal. I've deleted the answer for the meanwhile as I'm not really sure how to tackle this.

I don't think it deserves being a comment, as it's an actual answer. There's also no need to change the wording as it's the same question with a good and detailed explanation.

Comment: make it a wiki answer and use that question as duplicate target if the same occur in the future

Comment: @TemaniAfif What is the advantage of a wiki answer over a regular answer in this case?

Comment: you won't earn reputation from it and it's not really your answer. Anyone can update it like they want.

Comment: The link you left in the comments seems perfectly sufficient to me. I can't imagine that out of the other 42 answers the issue isn't explained by others also

Comment: @charlietfl I'm asking in the general case when I'm the first person answering.

Comment: The fact that a question is answered elsewhere doesn't mean that you can just link there. All answers must be on Stack Overflow. If you don't want to write a new answer, you can quote the external resource

Comment: @Dharman but then the answer will be a quote-only answer which might be discouraged

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to quote so much: quote a sufficient part to answer the question, and leave the link available for people who want to know more. Here's the part I would quote:

> Variables are simply names that refer to objects. Doing `y = x` doesn’t create a copy of the list – it creates a new variable `y` that refers to the same object `x` refers to. This means that there is only one object (the list), and both `x` and `y` refer to it.

That answers the "explain why it happens" part of the question sufficiently; the "how do I fix it" is not explained on that page of the docs. You could then add a paragraph explaining how to make a copy of the list; in your answer you quoted another docs page, but again there was no need to quote so much.

The problem with link-only answers is they become useless if the content of the link changes or moves. That means that as long as there is enough in your answer to make it useful even if the link rots, then it is not a link-only answer. You don't need to write your answer in such a way that it remains equally useful regardless of whether the link rots; only in such a way that it remains not-useless.

Remember also that unless the docs you're quoting from have a license allowing you to reproduce and redistribute as much of it as you want, it is much better to err on the side of quoting less, since that makes it more likely to be "fair use".

Comment: The rest of the FAQ brings forth more examples and further enhances the understanding of the OP, which I believe is important.
Even if I follow your advice, the answer will still be an entire quote taken from the FAQ and a link; is it encouraged?

Comment: @Bharel There might be differing views on this. Quoting the text, and providing attribution is of course a minimum requirement, but even then, if your answer consists *solely* of quoted text, there are mods who will summarily delete that answer. I would strongly suggest writing at least some part of the answer in your own words.

Comment: @Bharel Further enhancing people's understanding is of course important, but an answer on Stack Overflow should ideally stick to answering the specific question that was asked, because that is what makes the answer useful to people who have that question. Once you start explaining how the `+=` operator has different behaviour for different types in Python then you're not answering the question, you're just making it harder to find the information they were looking for. You may believe that also explaining that other thing makes your answer more useful, but on Stack Overflow the idea is ...

Comment: ... that people will know what information will be useful to them, and search for it. Yes, that assumption is not always true, so there is a balance to draw, but in general you should avoid explaining other things than what was asked about *unless* it is genuinely necessary to support an understanding of the actual answer to the question. Don't just add more information because you believe more information is always useful.